# Logstash start with error: Pipelines YAML file is empty

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

When I try start logstash server on my machine I get this error:

```
Sending Logstash's logs to D:/kibana/logstash-6.3.2/logs which is now configured
     via log4j2.properties
    ERROR: Pipelines YAML file is empty. Location: D:/kibana/logstash-6.3.2/config/p
    ipelines.yml
    usage:
      bin/logstash -f CONFIG_PATH [-t] [-r] [] [-w COUNT] [-l LOG]
      bin/logstash --modules MODULE_NAME [-M "MODULE_NAME.var.PLUGIN_TYPE.PLUGIN_NAM
    E.VARIABLE_NAME=VALUE"] [-t] [-w COUNT] [-l LOG]
      bin/logstash -e CONFIG_STR [-t] [--log.level fatal|error|warn|info|debug|trace
    ] [-w COUNT] [-l LOG]
      bin/logstash -i SHELL [--log.level fatal|error|warn|info|debug|trace]
      bin/logstash -V [--log.level fatal|error|warn|info|debug|trace]
      bin/logstash --help
    [2018-12-14T16:16:10,809][ERROR][org.logstash.Logstash    ] java.lang.IllegalSta
    teException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
```

I delite all and exctract new code(default configs) and get this error anyway.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to start your Logstash with multiple pipelines configuration:

> When you start Logstash without arguments, it will read the
>   pipelines.yml file and instantiate all pipelines specified in the
>   file. On the other hand, when you use -e or -f, Logstash ignores the
>   pipelines.yml file and logs a warning about it.

You can start Logstash specifying config file location:

```
logstash -f mypipeline.conf
```

or you can just configure your `pipelines.yml` file. I strongly advise to use pipelines configuration becuase it will be easier to expand Logstash in the future and you can specify resources for each pipeline.

An example configuration of `pipelines.yml`:

```
- pipeline.id: my_pipeline_name
  path.config: "/path/to/your/config/file.cfg"
  queue.type: persisted
```

Comment: but i am getting below error:- 
Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"input\", \"filter\", \"output\" at line 1, column 1 (byte 1)", :backtrace=>["C:/logstash/logstash-7.6.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:47:in

Answer (score 1):

If have isntalled the logstash recently using `brew`, just try going to

```
cd /usr/local/logstash/{version-number}
```

and run

```
bin/logstash -f "/path/to/your/pipeline/config.conf" --config.reload.automatic

brew service restart logstash
```

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/advanced-pipeline.html